# Transfer Learning API for Image Classification from Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been examining the latest version of [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) from tensorflow, but I ran into confusion between trained graph and saved model. To elaborate:

1. In Line 1307 in [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py),  we give the path to save our "trained graph". This is saved as a .pb file. This graph we then use to further classify our dataset (using [label_image.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py))
2. In the new version of [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py), there is also a saved_model path (In Line 1482). This also saves a .pb  file. The code explains that it is an "exported model" for "serving".

I do not understand the difference between the two .pb files (**output_graph.pb** and **saved_model.pb**) the code generates. What is the importance of saved_model.pb and where it can be used? What does "serving" mean here?

Any explanation or probably links to explanation would be of great help.

Thanks N Regards,

Pradip

Comment: The link are not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tensorflow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_basic) is a serving system that can be used to make your model available in production using docker container. The new format saves the model in a way that can be used as a serving object.